# Teradata - Calling a table with spaces in the name

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm connecting to a SQL Server database through Teradata SQL Assistant. The DBA created a new table in the database that I'm interested in, but he put spaces in the name of the table (e.g. `Daily Sales by Terminal`). I know in SQL Server, you can use `[]` around the name and it works fine. But that syntax doesn't seem to be working in Teradata. I even tried underscores and that didn't work either. I'm getting an error message that says:

> SELECT failed: 208: Invalid object name
>   'Reports.Daily_Sales_by_Terminal'.

Is there a way to call that table or will I just be forced to use SQL Server Studio?

```sql
SELECT * FROM Reports.Daily_Sales_by_Terminal
```

Comment: Btw, SQL Server also supports Standard SQL double quoted names instead of proprietary `[]`

Answer (score 4):

In Teradata you can wrap the name in quotes to qualify the object, example:

```
SELECT * FROM Schema."The Table Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes around the table name:

```
SELECT * FROM Reports."Daily Sales by Terminal";
```

You can add double quotes to other objects like database, table, view, etc. to use special characters (i.e. space) in the names.